# Magento 2.1.9 broken sorting

Tags: magento2, sort

On this online store - https://nammu.com/

Sorting is not working, all time gives random result for sort

I checked and changed the settings in the admin panel, in the category section and in the section configuration, did not help.

Having reviewed and tried many recommendations on stackexchange.com and on other resources did not help.

Even wrote my extension, 
[image]
but the same result

can someone suggest where to look further to fix the error

Thanks